# issue capturing the hashed URI parameters in Coldfusion

Tags: facebook, url, hash, coldfusion, uri

Is there a way to capture URI parameters with hash # in coldfusion. I am working on facebook login and facebook after authentication sending this access_token which I am unable to capture down in CF.

Any help will be apreciated.

http://dev.xyz.com/redirectfb.cfm?#**access_token=CAAUyoQQg6skBAJQAVhcARZCAR**&expires_in=5156508&code=AQBDV1c0Ib15GQ45fEkNsk_9jtE8wA9AjcCh4niZdVHOkkBH_OCLaOhj0tPy6nC-BTgG1qGYPYasDyadanAzEwzulo8PCzthfm

Comment: the only way to do this I think is capture it client-side and pass it to CF via ajax

Comment: You should be able to extract it from somewhere in the CGI scope, probably cgi.QUERY_STRING and then use some string manipulation to pull it out from there.

Comment: @andrewdixon No Andrew, the portion of the url past the hash is not even sent to the server, let alone Cold Fusion. As duncan said, and the duplicate link shows, a client-side intermediary must be involved.

Comment: @cfqueryparam - Ok fair enough, I didn't take that meaning from what duncan said. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Thanks guys, I got it working now. I captured the URL at client side (JQUery), and then reformat it using JS and redirected it